# removeClass JQuery

Tags: jquery

Quero adicionar uma classe em um link de uma lista, eu consegui, porém quero remover a classe quando clico em outro link da mesma lista, e que a classe permaneça somente no link clicado. adicionar eu adiciono porém quando clico em outro link, o link clicado anteriormente permanece com a classe. O que estou fazendo de errado???

## HTML

```
<li class="list-group-item">
  <a onclick="requestFile(this.id)" id="{{ content.id}}">

    <!--Colocar o status do log-->
    <span class=""></span>
    <!--Colocar o status do log-->

    <div class="media">
        <div class="media-left">
            <img class="icon-son-play" src="{% static "img/icons/play-gray.png" %}" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
            <h4 class="media-heading">{{ content.name}}</h4>
            {{ content.description}}
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

## JQuery

```
$(document).on('click', '.page_video_content ul li a', function() {

    $('.page_video_content ul li a span').removeClass('started');

    $('span', this).addClass('started');
    if($('span.started', this)) {
        $('span.started', this).css({
            'background': '#f3c03d'
        }).text("Assistindo");
    }
});
```

Comment: Podes mostrar o teu HTML?

Comment: Repara também que `if($('span.started', this)) {` vai sempre dar verdadeiro. Deves usar `.length` para saber se uma coleção jQuery está vazia ou não.

Comment: Somente esse trecho do HTML não mostra todos os elementos envolvidos na questão @Candido

Comment: Podes juntar o HTML renderizado? ou seja o que aparece no Browser quando esse script corre?

Comment: Sergio desculpa, mas não posso, é coisa de trabalho, eu nem deveria tá perguntando aq, porém isso tá me tirando do sério... Me desculpe, e obrigado por sua compreensão...

Comment: Você quer que a classe seja removida, mas o background laranja pode ficar no link anterior?

Comment: Identifiquei que quando clico em outro link, o background também deveria passar pro outro link, certo?

Comment: @Candido compreendo. Podes criar um exemplo no jsFiddle com código parecido e que reproduza o problema. Isso é jQuery simples, é só uma questão de vêr o teu HTML para poder dar um exemplo e explicar.

Comment: Olá Jhonnyjks, tbm não, o background será removido tbm...

Comment: Veja minha resposta abaixo!

Comment: Obrigado Sergio, por sua atenção, São pessoas como vc, que deicham esse mundo melhor!!!

Comment: Obrigado  Jhonnyjks! Vc me ajudou muito! O que eu comentei com o Sergio serve pra vc tbm, Vlu Cara!!!!

Comment: @Candido a resposta aceite "ajuda" ou "resolve" o problema? Eu ainda acho que o problema não foi descrito de forma a podermos reproduzir...

Comment: @Sergio, deu certo, o que eu queria! Meu único problema agora é remover o texto "Assistindo", porém isso eu vou fazer ainda!!! Obrigado!!!

Comment: Adicione `$('.started').text("Assistir");` Apos a linha q tem `removeClass(`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue a resposta, podendo ser executada aqui mesmo!

```js
$(document).on('click', '.page_video_content ul li a', function() {
    alert('lol');
  $('.started').css('background', '');
  $('.started').removeClass('started');

    $('span', this).addClass('started');
    if($('span.started', this)) {
        $('span.started', this).css({
            'background': '#f3c03d'
        }).text("Assistindo");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page_video_content">
  <ul>
<li class="list-group-item">
  <a onclick="requestFile(this.id)" id="{{ content.id}}">

    <!--Colocar o status do log-->
    <span class="started">Assistindo</span>
    <!--Colocar o status do log-->

    <div class="media">
        <div class="media-left">
            <img class="icon-son-play" src="{% static "img/icons/play-gray.png" %}" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
            <h4 class="media-heading">{{ content.name}}</h4>
            {{ content.description}}
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
  </li>
  
  <li class="list-group-item">
  <a onclick="requestFile(this.id)" id="{{ content.id}}">

    <!--Colocar o status do log-->
    <span class="">Assistindo</span>
    <!--Colocar o status do log-->

    <div class="media">
        <div class="media-left">
            <img class="icon-son-play" src="{% static "img/icons/play-gray.png" %}" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
            <h4 class="media-heading">{{ content.name}}</h4>
            {{ content.description}}
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
  </li>
  
  <li class="list-group-item">
  <a onclick="requestFile(this.id)" id="{{ content.id}}">

    <!--Colocar o status do log-->
    <span class="">Assistindo</span>
    <!--Colocar o status do log-->

    <div class="media">
        <div class="media-left">
            <img class="icon-son-play" src="{% static "img/icons/play-gray.png" %}" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
            <h4 class="media-heading">{{ content.name}}</h4>
            {{ content.description}}
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
  </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Porquê `$('.page_video_content ul li a').click(function() {`? assim não tem delegação...

Comment: Obrigado meu querido! Você me ajudou muito!!!

Comment: @Sergio, ele precisa que todos os elementos 'a'  contidos nos 'li' recebam o listener...

Comment: @Jhonnyjks mas o teu seletor é igual ao dele, somente sem delegar o evento. Se esse HTML fôr dinamico isso vai falhar certo?

Comment: @Sergio sim, uma vez que os listeners precisam ser recarregados caso sejam adicionados novos elementos 'a'. Porém, por algum motivo, do modo que estava não funfou... estou vendo...

Comment: @Sergio e Candido, fiz a alteração da linha para ter delegação, porém não funfa no sistema de execução aqui no SO, mas no navegador funcionou normal.